# Update packet fontconfig to newer version in ubuntu 18 LTS

Tags: apt, upgrade, fonts, versions

I would like to update my packet `fontconfig` to the last release 2.13.1. My machine is running Ubuntu 18.04 and this packet is only available in `bionic` in version 2.12.6 ([ubuntu packages fontconfig](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=fontconfig&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all)):

```
mael:src$ apt show fontconfig
Package: fontconfig
Version: 2.12.6-0ubuntu2
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

I can see that the version I'm looking for is available in `disco`, `eoan` or `focal`. How can I do to grab only this packet with `apt`?

Thanks for your answer,

Maël

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! See my answer [here.](https://askubuntu.com/a/1225013/225694)

Answer (score 0):

[Backup all critical data on your LTS system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc/586172#586172) and upgrade to 20.04 which should be available [here](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop) when it's released on [April 23rd, 2020.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseSchedule) On that date you should be able to utilize the [standard upgrade method.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu) If you can't wait you can obtain a daily build [here.](http://www.cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/) Be aware that Ubuntu 20.04 daily builds will contain bugs and broken packages, and you may encounter many usability and/or stability issues as features are added (and in some cases removed). 20.04 has fontconfig 2.13.1-2ubuntu2 currently available [in the repositories.](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=fontconfig&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) This approach should avoid many of the pitfalls that can occur when blending packages approved for different releases.

Comment: Hi Elder Geek and thanks for your answer! My computer starts to become a bit old, so I told myself that I will stop upgrading to newer Ubuntu releases from now on... Do you think it makes sense? In the meantime I will try to pin my packet or even build it from the sources...

Comment: @Mema5 I recommended that which I believe makes sense. Cheers!